# Bend extruded text

Tags: bezier-curves, extrude, 3d-printing, text-object

**New try (10/24, 3PM):**

[image]

Hello! I set both the shape and curve origins to the World Origin (0,0), but I'm not sure if that's the right spot for both. When I try to animate the 'Follow Path' constraint, the text seems shorter and isn't moving correctly. I've uploaded a new file.

Adding the Curve modifier has been helpful. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. I extruded the text and converted it into a mesh.
2. I added a curve.
3. I applied a Remesh modifier to the text (mesh).
4. I added a Curve modifier with the Bezier curve as the Curve object and -z as the deform axis, along with the Follow Path constraint.

If you have any recommended settings for both modifiers and constraints, please let me know.

After converting the text curve to a mesh, what's the best way to make the mesh fit the entire curve?(Can I extrude the shape after?) My initial extruded text is shorter than the curve I drew.

I couldn't extrude it after retopologizing (applying the Remesh modifier). I couldn't select the top part of the 'H' to extrude.

---

original:
[image]

I'm trying to bend some text that I've extruded. I considered using the Text on Curve feature, but it's not working correctly; the orientation is wrong.

Even if I change the origin (origin to geometry), it doesn't help. Is there a different method to create what I want, like in my drawing, with curved text?

[image: screenshot of my blender workspace]

I tried placing the text to a curve as well.
[image: curved extruded text drawing plan]

Comment: pls provide blend file. We have no idea of your settings and what you did. thx.

Comment: Just uploaded the file, thank you! I tried both constraints (after converting curve to mesh) and text on curve. Instead of having the extruded letters straight, I want to twist/curve some parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you wanna achieve?

[image]

There are several things, which have to be right:

1. both origins have to be on the same point so that it works
2. You have to convert the text to a mesh
3. the mesh must have a good topology so that Blender can bend it. I used a remesh modifier after i converted the extruded A to mesh.

[image]

4. apply the remesh modifier, then use the curve modifier to bend it. If this still doesn't work, please reupload the new "try" to your question, thx.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to achieve! If you don't mind, can you share how origins are set up on that file? As you wrote "both origins have to be on the same point so that it works", I am now trying to figure out matching two origins. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello! Just added a new file to my question (original post), thank you for sharing your expertise. This is helping me a lot! Issue that I am experiencing: the text is not following the curve (cannot animate) and the entire shape is shorter/smaller than the curve (cannot extrude. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Could you check where the origins should be placed (or any suggested areas that origin of the curve and the shape should both be at) and review the steps I've taken to see if there's anything unnecessary? Thanks a lot!!

As I re-read your response, I realized I can adjust the shape's position by changing the Z location in the Transform settings like in your GIF.

Comment: you can have the origins whereever you want, they should just be both in the same place if you wanna make the object follow the curve exactly. If you move one origin a bit, you will see, it will be kind of "offsetted" - but still follow the curve - but often looks weird if the offset is bigger.